# ElasticSearch version conflict exception when deleting by query

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, version-conflict-engine-exception

I'm using ElasticSearch in my Laravel app and recently I've implemented the option to allow for deletion of documents from the Elastic Search index. The problem is that I keep getting the `version_conflict_engine_exception` error.

My code looks like this:

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'invoices',
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'must' => [
                    ['term' => ['user_id' => $userId]]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'refresh' => true,
];

Elasticsearch::deleteByQuery($params);
```

After reading the official docs I get that a `'conflicts' => 'proceed'` parameter can be added and this should solve the problem. But I feel like I'm only hiding the issue, not actually solving it. I know for sure that no other operation is performed on that document in the same time, so no reason for the version to change, but this error keeps popping up.

```
{
  "took": 1189,
  "timed_out": false,
  "total": 47,
  "deleted": 0,
  "batches": 1,
  "version_conflicts": 47,
  "noops": 0,
  "retries": {
    "bulk": 0,
    "search": 0
  },
  "throttled_millis": 0,
  "requests_per_second": -1,
  "throttled_until_millis": 0,
  "failures": {
    "index": "invoices",
    "type": "_doc",
    "id": "6e6bd47a-c225-4d7f-8798-cc1275b0363c",
    "cause": {
      "type": "version_conflict_engine_exception",
      "reason": "[6e6bd47a-c225-4d7f-8798-cc1275b0363c]: version conflict, required seqNo [667648], primary term [7]. but no document was found",
      "index_uuid": "7wBzPBXYT4Kfx8jP1SjSNA",
      "shard": "0",
      "index": "invoices"
    },
    "status": 409
  }
}
```

Could there be something else to this that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the full `version_conflict_engine_exception` error that you get?

Comment: Updated the post with the exception details.

Comment: This could happen if you (for some reason) send this query twice at the same time. ElasticSearch first determines the Ids to delete and then deletes them so if you do this twice at the same time both queries might determine the same ids but only one will get to delete them. I know you said you know no other query is performed at the same time, but are you absolutely sure? How are you calling this query?

Comment: What is the refresh interval on the `invoices` index?

Comment: @apokryfos, the query is called as shown in the example above. I'm using [this](https://github.com/cviebrock/laravel-elasticsearch) package.

Comment: @Val, will check that, I don't know exactly.

Comment: @Val, the refresh interval is the default one, 1 second.

Comment: @Cosmin did you ever find the solution to this?